# How to display firestore data of map datatype?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am just learning about using firestore in a react native application and created a collection of fields containing map datatype which creates a hierarchical structure. But I cannot find any tutorial online on how to display such data. If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks.

[This is the document which contains the fields of map data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKr6.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you print the data type "map" from firestore, it will show `[Object, Object]`. This means it is a JavaScript object. To view this in React Native you must get the object values from the object.

```
let mapData = Object.values(snapshot.data().mapVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
 firebase.initializeApp({
    "projectId": "my-project-id",
    "apiKey": "my-api-key",
    "authDomain": "my-project.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://my-project.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "my-project-id.appspot.com/",
    "messagingSenderId": "my-messaging-sender-id"
})
const db = firebase.firestore();

db
    .collection('services')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot
        .docs
        .forEach(doc => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(doc._document.data.toString()))
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt reply. But unfortunately, this code is not printing anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const createData = (drink) => { db.collection("drinks").add(drink)
.then(() => showToast({ type: 'success', text: 'drink added' }))
.catch((error) => showToast({ type: 'danger', text: error.message }));};export default createData;
```

I am assuming you have some toast messages for visual feedback, also that you have initialized your Firebase instance.